# Best way to run long running Sql Scripts in winforms and keep UI responsive

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, async-await, smo

I have been working to write a SQL installer for my application and haven't been given a lot of time to work on it therefore its a bit dirty.  My UI thread collects values from the form, plugs them into a series of SQL scritps and then one by one kicks them of "asynchronously" using SMO.  Here is a sample of the calling method on the UI thread:

```
        private static bool BeginScriptExecution(Dictionary<string, string[]> scripts)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var script in scripts)
                {
                    if (script.Key.Length > 0)
                    {
                        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
                        conn = ReplaceDatabaseName(GetConnectionString(), script.Value[0]);
                        if (TestSqlConnection())
                        {
                            if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["useSMO"] == "1")
                            {

                                if (!RunDatabaseCommandsSmo(conn, script.Key, script.Value[1]).Result)
                                {
                                    throw new Exception("Script failed to run.  Error in SMO functions.");
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if (!RunDatabaseCommandsNonSmo(conn, script.Key, script.Value[1]))
                                {
                                    throw new Exception("Script failed to run.  Non-SMO related failure.");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Connection not available.  Script failed to run");
                        }
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is my async method to run the command using SMO:

```
        public static async Task<bool> RunDatabaseCommandsSmo(SqlConnection connectionString, string scriptText, string scriptName)
        {
            Helper.UpdateProgressLabel(scriptName);
            bool isSuccess = false;

            try
            {
                ServerConnection srvCon = new ServerConnection(connectionString);
                Server server = new Server(srvCon);
                //script = scriptText;
                if (scriptName.Contains("Creating Database")||scriptName.Contains("Building objects"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        isSuccess = await Task.Run(() => RunCommand(scriptText, server))
                            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext:false);
                        return isSuccess;
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error("Cannot create database");
                        log.Error(ex.StackTrace.ToString());

                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(scriptText);
                        isSuccess = await Task.Run(() => RunTransaction(scriptText, server, srvCon))
                            .ConfigureAwait(continueOnCapturedContext: false);

                        return isSuccess;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        log.Error(string.Format("Error writing transaction from script {0}.  Installation halted - check inner exception.", scriptName));
                        log.Error(ex.ToString());
                        log.Error(ex.StackTrace.ToString());

                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(string.Format("Error writing transaction from script {0}.  Installation halted - check inner exception.", scriptName));
                log.Error(ex.StackTrace.ToString());

                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is the code running the transactions:

```
        static bool RunCommand(string script, Server server)
        {
            try
            {
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }

        static bool RunTransaction(string script, Server server, ServerConnection srvCon)
        {
            try
            {
                srvCon.BeginTransaction();
                server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
                srvCon.CommitTransaction();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                srvCon.RollBackTransaction();
                log.Error(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Before I started moving towards async I was running all on the UI thread and the form would give me "Not Responding" until the script returned completed.  Once I moved to this style of async the app is a bit more responsive and I no longer get not responding, but I am not sure of this method and whether or not it is correct use of async.  Can someone let me know how I can alter my code to make this work correctly?  There are 4 scripts that run and must run in specific order meaning script 2 cannot run until script 1 returns.

Comment: I believe there is a executenonqueryasync method

Comment: I am using SMO, I do not believe there is an async method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good way to use asynchronous tasks is using a background worker,

take a look at the code example here:
[Background Worker](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)

Comment: Will this style using background worker allow the sequential execution of the scripts?  I want the UI to remain responsive so the user can cancel (click X) and not get "Not Resonding" but I don't want any other processing other than the scripts.  Once the user executes the install the background worker should run scripts one by one while the UI thread waits (but remains responsive).  Will this method lend itself to the style I am looking for?

Comment: yes, it will, background worker acts as another thread that runs in the background. and lets the UI still be responsive

Comment: If the only requirement is to have the UI remain responsive, then Background worker is ok (if a bit obsolete). If you also want the collection of work items to be executed concurrently, then Task Parallel Library (TPL)/async/await is a better bet

Comment: If you don't want any other processing, the best option is still a BackgroundWorker, but to also create a *modal* dialog to start the worker with just a progress bar and cancel button.

Comment: So I just tried to wire this up in the foreach loop that calls the RunDatabaseCommandsSmo method.  Seems my logic is trying to create a new BW for every loop.  i would assume this is not the best way.  Should I create a collection of objects for all the scripts and put the foreach loop that iterates and runs the scripts consecutively in the dowork method on the BW?  That seems to make more sense to me.

Comment: yes you should, all the main work of the background worker should be inside the DoWork method

Answer (score 1):

If B.G. is the way you go, here is an example: [How to: Implement a Form That Uses a Background Operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-implement-a-form-that-uses-a-background-operation)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BackgroundWorkerExample
{   
    public class FibonacciForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {   
        private int numberToCompute = 0;
        private int highestPercentageReached = 0;

        private System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown numericUpDown1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button startAsyncButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button cancelAsyncButton;
        private System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar progressBar1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label resultLabel;
        private System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1;

        public FibonacciForm()
        {   
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeBackgroundWorker();
        }

        // Set up the BackgroundWorker object by 
        // attaching event handlers. 
        private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
        {
            backgroundWorker1.DoWork += 
                new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted += 
                new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
            backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += 
                new ProgressChangedEventHandler(
            backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
        }

        private void startAsyncButton_Click(System.Object sender, 
            System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Reset the text in the result label.
            resultLabel.Text = String.Empty;

            // Disable the UpDown control until 
            // the asynchronous operation is done.
            this.numericUpDown1.Enabled = false;

            // Disable the Start button until 
            // the asynchronous operation is done.
            this.startAsyncButton.Enabled = false;

            // Enable the Cancel button while 
            // the asynchronous operation runs.
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Enabled = true;

            // Get the value from the UpDown control.
            numberToCompute = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;

            // Reset the variable for percentage tracking.
            highestPercentageReached = 0;

            // Start the asynchronous operation.
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(numberToCompute);
        }

        private void cancelAsyncButton_Click(System.Object sender, 
            System.EventArgs e)
        {   
            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            this.backgroundWorker1.CancelAsync();

            // Disable the Cancel button.
            cancelAsyncButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        // This event handler is where the actual,
        // potentially time-consuming work is done.
        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, 
            DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {   
            // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            // Assign the result of the computation
            // to the Result property of the DoWorkEventArgs
            // object. This is will be available to the 
            // RunWorkerCompleted eventhandler.
            e.Result = ComputeFibonacci((int)e.Argument, worker, e);
        }

        // This event handler deals with the results of the
        // background operation.
        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
            object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Next, handle the case where the user canceled 
                // the operation.
                // Note that due to a race condition in 
                // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled
                // flag may not have been set, even though
                // CancelAsync was called.
                resultLabel.Text = "Canceled";
            }
            else
            {
                // Finally, handle the case where the operation 
                // succeeded.
                resultLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
            }

            // Enable the UpDown control.
            this.numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;

            // Enable the Start button.
            startAsyncButton.Enabled = true;

            // Disable the Cancel button.
            cancelAsyncButton.Enabled = false;
        }

        // This event handler updates the progress bar.
        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,
            ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        // This is the method that does the actual work. For this
        // example, it computes a Fibonacci number and
        // reports progress as it does its work.
        long ComputeFibonacci(int n, BackgroundWorker worker, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            // The parameter n must be >= 0 and <= 91.
            // Fib(n), with n > 91, overflows a long.
            if ((n < 0) || (n > 91))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "value must be >= 0 and <= 91", "n");
            }

            long result = 0;

            // Abort the operation if the user has canceled.
            // Note that a call to CancelAsync may have set 
            // CancellationPending to true just after the
            // last invocation of this method exits, so this 
            // code will not have the opportunity to set the 
            // DoWorkEventArgs.Cancel flag to true. This means
            // that RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs.Cancelled will
            // not be set to true in your RunWorkerCompleted
            // event handler. This is a race condition.

            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {   
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {   
                if (n < 2)
                {   
                    result = 1;
                }
                else
                {   
                    result = ComputeFibonacci(n - 1, worker, e) + 
                             ComputeFibonacci(n - 2, worker, e);
                }

                // Report progress as a percentage of the total task.
                int percentComplete = 
                    (int)((float)n / (float)numberToCompute * 100);
                if (percentComplete > highestPercentageReached)
                {
                    highestPercentageReached = percentComplete;
                    worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }


        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.numericUpDown1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NumericUpDown();
            this.startAsyncButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.cancelAsyncButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.resultLabel = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.progressBar1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
            this.backgroundWorker1 = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown1)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // numericUpDown1
            // 
            this.numericUpDown1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 16);
            this.numericUpDown1.Maximum = new System.Decimal(new int[] {
            91,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.numericUpDown1.Minimum = new System.Decimal(new int[] {
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.numericUpDown1.Name = "numericUpDown1";
            this.numericUpDown1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 20);
            this.numericUpDown1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.numericUpDown1.Value = new System.Decimal(new int[] {
            1,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            // 
            // startAsyncButton
            // 
            this.startAsyncButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 72);
            this.startAsyncButton.Name = "startAsyncButton";
            this.startAsyncButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(120, 23);
            this.startAsyncButton.TabIndex = 1;
            this.startAsyncButton.Text = "Start Async";
            this.startAsyncButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.startAsyncButton_Click);
            // 
            // cancelAsyncButton
            // 
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Enabled = false;
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(153, 72);
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Name = "cancelAsyncButton";
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(119, 23);
            this.cancelAsyncButton.TabIndex = 2;
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Text = "Cancel Async";
            this.cancelAsyncButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.cancelAsyncButton_Click);
            // 
            // resultLabel
            // 
            this.resultLabel.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            this.resultLabel.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(112, 16);
            this.resultLabel.Name = "resultLabel";
            this.resultLabel.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(160, 23);
            this.resultLabel.TabIndex = 3;
            this.resultLabel.Text = "(no result)";
            this.resultLabel.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
            // 
            // progressBar1
            // 
            this.progressBar1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(18, 48);
            this.progressBar1.Name = "progressBar1";
            this.progressBar1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(256, 8);
            this.progressBar1.Step = 2;
            this.progressBar1.TabIndex = 4;
            // 
            // backgroundWorker1
            // 
            this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            this.backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            // 
            // FibonacciForm
            // 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 118);
            this.Controls.Add(this.progressBar1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.resultLabel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.cancelAsyncButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.startAsyncButton);
            this.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDown1);
            this.Name = "FibonacciForm";
            this.Text = "Fibonacci Calculator";
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.numericUpDown1)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }
        #endregion

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new FibonacciForm());
        }
    }
}
```